# Groovy support in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I'm trying to set up Groovy in NetBeans 7.4, apparently it should already be installed and ready to use.

I'm following the guide in the NetBeans documentation, but step 6 says "Select Groovy Class in the Groovy category."

When I right click in the project to add a new file, i have no Groovy Category! What am I missing here?

Comment: What version of Netbeans?  Have you installed the Groovy plugin? As it stands, this question is impossible to answer

Comment: I'm using netbeans 7.4 - Apparently you shouldnt need a plugin after version 6.5

Comment: The [download matrix](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) shows otherwise

Comment: Well spotted Tim! I downloaded and installed the 'All' option and I now i have the right options. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the "ALL" variant of Netbeans, or install the Groovy Plugin from inside Netbeans to get Groovy Support :-)